# Apache proxy pass URL to avoide # from Angular login page

Tags: angular, apache, angular-ui-router

Our developers are working on Angular development and they implemented an application and its login URL as follows http://app./ag/#/can/auth/login. They wants to clean this url by removing # from this login URL.Is it possible to create Apache proxy pass to remove this # from this URL?
I mean we need to access the above URL by http://app./ag/can/auth/login.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove this from the Angualr configuration :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes/*, { useHash: true }*/)
```

This will remove the hash from the URL.

Comment: We are using a Angular routing. When we set this the routing is not working. Is there any way to do this using Apache level?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working, that's the basics of Angular routing. Unless you mitaged your question and you're using **AngularJS**, and not *Angular* ?

Comment: We are using the same application for different customers with their brand names. Using angular routing for this case and it is working the branding URL something like followings

*http://app-URL/ser/#/ken/auth/login*
*http://app-URL/ser/#/usa/auth/login*

We are trying to remove the # from customer phasing URL. What I understand it # will come in the url when we enabled this kind of routing in Angular level. So that we are planning to remove # from Customer phasing url with Apache proxy pass rule

Comment: We are using the same application for different customers with their brand names. Using angular routing for this case and it is working the branding URL something like followings

https://app-URL/ser/#/ken/auth/login, 
https://app-URL/ser/#/usa/auth/login

We are trying to remove the # from customer phasing URL. What I understand it # will come in the url when we enabled this kind of routing in Angular level. So that we are planning to remove # from Customer phasing url with Apache proxy pass rule

Comment: That doesn't answer me. Are you using angular or angularJs ?

Comment: We are using Angular

Comment: The my answer should work. If it doesn't, then provide a [mcve] reproducing the case where it doesn't work.

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you roni for posting this and thank you trichetriche for you valuable information.

In the above example url http://app.com/ag/can/auth/login. We can do routing without hash easily if the route is static. We need can in url as dynamic and we are looking for the same to achieve by angular routing concept. Is that possible for us to route a dynamic url without hash.. Waiting for your reply..

Comment: I told you and I'm telling you again : if you want to remove the pound sign, you do it by changing the code of your front-end, not by configuring your server.

Comment: We didn't get the page requested by direct entering url in browser..Shows Not Found.. @trichetriche

Comment: I give up. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @roni for posting this and thank you @trichetriche for you valuable information.

In the above example url  http://app.com/ag/**can**/auth/login. We can do routing without hash easily if the route is static. We need **can**  in url as dynamic and we are looking for the same to achieve by angular routing concept. Is that possible for us to route a dynamic url without hash.. Waiting for your reply..